# How to use npm in ASP.NET Core 2, while using Visual Studio For Mac?

Tags: asp.net-core, npm, visual-studio-mac

I'm building ASP.NET Core 2 web application and I'm trying to add jquery. In Visual Studio 2017 for Windows, I would click right on the project, click "Add" and then select "npm Configuration File" from the ***Web*** tab, here:

[image]

After opening the ***package.json*** file and adding new dependencies by simply editing the file, we can see "npm" folder under "Dependencies":

[image]

My problem is, I'm trying to do the same in Visual Studio for Mac and it doesn't seem the same. First of all I'm missing "npm Configuration File" after selecting "Add new item" to the project. When I create new empty json file, name it "package.json" and fill it up with the correct schema ("version", "name", "dependencies", etc) - it still doesn't work.

Am I missing something? How can I use npm in ASP.NET Core 2 project, while using Visual Studio For Mac?

Thanks!

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac does not have integrated support for NPM. You will have to use the command line to install npm packages. You may want to post this as a [feature request on the Visual Studio for Mac developer community forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/41/visual-studio-for-mac.html?type=idea).

Comment: @MattWard Hi Matt, thanks for this suggestion. So, I would use npm to get jquery and then copy paste it to my project structure manually?

Comment: You would have to edit the package.json file, add the dependencies, such as jquery, using the text editor, then from the command line run `npm install` to download the files. I would not be copying the files into the project structure manually. Use npm to download them. If you need the files in a particular location, such as wwwroot, then I would look at modifying the project so it does this automatically on build, or you can look at using something like gulp to copy the files you need across to the wwwroot folder.